# Spring Batch Parallel reading from DB

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, spring-batch

How can I implement parallel reading from DB in Spring Batch?

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html I can implement mulithreaded step, however, I have to implement SynchronizedItemStreamReader for my reader. Therefore all my queries to DB are consecutive because of it.

Comment: What do you want to parallelise the reading or the processing?

Comment: Each chunk executes in new thread but method of reader doRead() is synchronized. That means I have concurrent execution only in processor and writer. My goal is to read  in non synchronized mode.

Answer (score 1):

`JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread safe because it wrap a single non thread safe `ResulSet`. This is why in multithread environment you need to `synchronized` access on it.

On the other hand the `JdbcPagingItemReader` is thread safe. When using multiple threads, each chunk is executed in it's own thread. If you've configured the page size to match the commit-interval, that means each page is processed in the same thread.

Now most of the time we need scaling rather at processing and write time than during read. Read are in general faster enough to support our scalability need.
But as I said if you really need this you should go with the out-of-the-box paging reader or by writing your own thread safe reader.